# get the label from apex:outputlabel tag using jQuery

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I am actually trying to get the associated label of a apex input tag to do some javascript validations. Here are my tags below:

```
<apex:outputlabel value="Account" for="NewContactAccountSelect" />
<apex:inputField id="NewContactAccountSelect" value="{!mergeField}" /> 
<apex:outputlabel value="Last Name" for="NewContactLastName" />
<input type="text" id="NewContactLastName" />
<!-- Other code -->
```

and there are like mix of HTML input tags and apex:input Tags. I have tried something using jQuery:

```
var RequiredFields = [];
var NewContactAccountSelect = jQuery("[id$=NewContactAccountSelect]");
var NewContactLastName = jQuery("[id$=NewContactLastName]");
RequiredFields.push(NewContactAccountSelect );
RequiredFields.push(NewContactLastName);

// And to retrive the label for it, I used:

jQuery(RequiredFields).each(function(index,field)
{ 
  jQuery("label[for$="+jQuery(field).attr('id')+"]").html().trim();
  //other code to do validation.
}
```

However,`jQuery(NewContactAccountSelect).attr('id')` will not retrieve the exact Id (since, it included the partial Ids as well) for visualforce tags and throws me the following error.

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: label[for$=j_id0:j_id106:j_id107:j_id108:j_id117:newContactForm:NewContactAccountSelect]

Any help to get the label of that inputField tag?

Also, another question: Is it possible to remove the partialId's added by salesforce and get the actual Id of form element by using javascript, jQuery etc..,?

Comment: can't you just use `jQuery("label[for$="NewContactAccountSelect"]").html().trim();` ? Just a thought

Comment: I expected your question and I updated my actual question.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "partial id" in your question? Are you referring to the `j_idN:` values in the rendered element id attributes?

Comment: @MarkPond Yes, Mark. The DOM Id's added by salesforce through out the hierarchy when we don't specify externally by `Id` attribute.

Comment: It is more efficient and less likely to cause false positives if you use a class selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need quotes around the DOM id value in the `for` attribute selector. You also do not need the `$` to apply 'ends with' selector matching, you already know the exact id value of the field being targeted and can use it directly.

You have this:

```
jQuery("label[for$=" + jQuery(field).attr('id') + "]")
```

instead you want do this (note the single quotes and the dropped $ modifier):

```
jQuery("label[for='" + jQuery(field).attr('id') + "']")
```

which would evaluate like this at runtime and match the label:
(presuming the label actually *has* a `for` attribute on it with this value)

```
jQuery("label[for='j_id0:j_id106:j_id107:j_id108:j_id117:newContactForm:NewContactAccountSelect']")
```

Somewhat related, if you add ids to all of the `<apex:` tags in your page, you can gain a slightly better looking element id hierarchy - if that is important to you. For example, if you give the `<apex:page` tag an `id="thePage"`, the first node in the element id value would be `thePage` instead of `j_id0`.

---

> Also, another question: Is it possible to remove the partialId's added by salesforce and get the actual Id of form element by using javascript, jQuery etc..,?

There is no such thing as a partial ID. Element id values are supposed to be unique in the page. In order to accomplish this when VF renders HTML, the hierarchy of tags in the page are evaluated and the id value of the DOM element is constructed in a way that guarantees uniqueness.

It looks like you have learned about the 'ends with' `$` selector modifier but if you want to output the a DOM id value using a VF-native feature, you can do so with the `$Component` global function. This will render out the DOM ID of the component into the page.

For instance, if you were to add `alert('{!$Component.NewContactAccountSelect}');` to your VF markup and you did it someplace where the renderer could find that component in the hierarchy, in your page source you would see `alert('j_id0:j_id106:j_id107:j_id108:j_id117:newContactForm:NewContactAccountSelect');` and have an alert popped with that string value in it.

If `$Component.NewContactAccountSelect` couldn't be found in the hierarchy, you'll just get an empty string there in the alert.

Documentation about best practices for referencing component ids in JavaScript: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1api.meta/salesforce1api/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
jQuery("[id$='NewContactAccountSelect']");
```

To get labels Id use this:

```
jQuery( "label" ).each(function( i ) {
  console.log( (i+1) + ": ID: " + $( this ).attr('id') );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From you code it seems you have used `newContactForm` as the form id. So you can use the following expression to get the input field. Hope this helps. If not please post a little bit more code snippet showing the complete DOM structure.

```
var NewContactAccountSelect = document.getElementById("{!$Component.newContactForm.NewContactAccountSelect}");
```

More details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_component.htm).